# Generate Sequence in RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I couldn't find an easy way to generate a seq and take the column mean in RcppArmadillo? Is there any simple solution for

```
colMeans(G[(N_burn+1):N_Gibbs,])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes it the third question of yours for which I tell you to just go to the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).  The post on [Armadillo subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/) has pretty much all you need, the [Armadillo API documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) and the [Rcpp documentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) have the rest:

- Armadillo uses `unsigned int` types to index
- so create an index vector in `uint`
- subset the original vector (or matrix column)
- use eg Rcpp's "Sugar" function `mean()` will will take a vector on input

and you're done.

Comment: Thx. There are too many things to learn about rcpp syntax. Another solution might be mean(G.rows(N_burn-1,N_Gibbs-1),0).